# Include comments form in plugin page

Tags: plugins, comments, include

I want to include the comments form on a page generated by my plugin. I got the post id I want to attach the comments to, but I can't get any of the Wordpress comments functions to work.

Tried to create a Wordpress loop within my plugin page like this, but the comments form won´t show up:

```
$args =  array ('post_type'=> 'cpt', 'p' => $post_id );
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) :
        while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();
        comment_form();
endwhile; endif;
wp_reset_postdata();
```

Comment: If you just need [`comment_form`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/comment_form), there are an argument `post_id`, you don't have to include it inside `WP_Query`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just as @Jevuska mentioned, you can use the $post_id as an argument here, in fact, you can also use a ton of optional $args as well `<?php comment_form( $args, $post_id ); ?>`

You can find the information in the Codex here:  https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/comment_form

Answer (score -1):

Thanks! Found the problem: 
I activated comments in settings, but there´s a checkbox for each post in the post edit screen. Without that activated, it won´t even throw an error.